# How to call a method in a taskScheduler?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using a **taskscheduler** to run my application after some time interval. The code is shown below,
but i want to run/call a **method** after my application has started.

```
using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            // Create a new task definition and assign properties
            TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
            td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Open App";
            // Create a trigger that will fire the task now
            Trigger tg = Trigger.CreateTrigger(TaskTriggerType.Time);
            Trigger tri = Trigger.CreateTrigger(TaskTriggerType.Event);


            tg.StartBoundary = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);

            td.Triggers.Add(tg);
            // Create an action that will launch Notepad whenever the trigger fires
            td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction(@"any.exe", null, null));
            // Register the task in the root folder

            ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(@"Test", td);


        }
```

`
what i need to change in my code to run/call method after application has started. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you'll have to give more information if you want help. if you start "any.exe" why not start whatever application you want in "any.exe"?

Answer (score 0):

The following code uses XML to load the task, but it can give you the missing code for registering for the task scheduler:

```
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            var folder = ts.RootFolder.SubFolders.FirstOrDefault(folderItem => folderItem.Name
                    == folderName);

            //folder doesn't exist, we will create it
            if (folder == null)
            {
                folder = ts.RootFolder.CreateFolder(folderName);
            }
            string xmlTaskData = string.Empty;
            if (File.Exists(fileLocation))
            {
                xmlTaskData = File.ReadAllText(fileLocation);
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }

            var task = folder.Tasks.FirstOrDefault(taskInFolder => taskInFolder.Name == taskName);

            //doesn't exist, we will add it using default xml
            if (task == null)
            {
                task = CreateTask(ts, folder, taskName, xmlTaskData);
            }

            if (task != null)
            {
                // enable/disable the task
                task.Enabled = add;
                task.Definition.Settings.Enabled = add;

                task.RegisterChanges();

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: we can't call any event or method after the application started because this code work properly for starting the application automatically, but i want to do some automatic work when application has started and hence i want to call a particular method.